# Compilation error when declaring a pointer to an array of pointers

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I noticed the following code in one Objective-C library (https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-ios-sdk):

```
NSArray<NSString*> *scope;
```

It gives me compilation errors and I didn't find anything related to this issue on the issue tracker.

> /Pods/VK-ios-sdk/library/Source/Views/VKAuthorizeController.h:36:57:
>   Expected '>'

Why? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using latest version of XCode. Lightweight generics are not supported in XCode 6x - I've just checked and receive the same error in XCode 6.1. Code compiled without issues with XCode 7.2.

Comment: How can I update XCode? I don't see any updates in AppStore

Comment: What version do you use? Check XCode About in menu